# Angular Ajax call, ng-repeat not showing

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, angularjs

The Js

```
var app = angular.module('app' , ['ui.router']);

app.controller('HeaderController',function( $scope , $http ){

    $http.get("/data/main_menu.php")
    .success(function(data){
        $scope.Menus = data;
    });

});
```

The HTML

```
<header ng-controller="HeaderController as header">
<ul id="menu_categories">
    <li ng-repeat="menu in header.Menus">{{ menu.name }}</li>
</ul>
```

The /data/main_menu.php

```
<?php
  $menu = array(
    array('name' => 'FACE'),
    array('name' => 'BODY'),
    array('name' => 'HAIR'),
    array('name' => 'MEN'),
    array('name' => 'BABIES & KIDS'),
    array('name' => 'SUN'),
    array('name' => 'AROMATHERAPY')
  );
  echo json_encode($menu);
?>
```

I tried an update function in Controller or defining the $scope.Menus outside of $http.get

Can you help me..? Might be somthing litle ! Thank you !

Comment: What does the response look like? `console.log(data)` and post the result

Comment: Array[1]
0: Array[7]
0: Object
name: "FACE"
__proto__: Object
1: Object
name: "BODY"
__proto__: Object
2: Object
3: Object
4: Object
5: Object
6: Object
length: 7
__proto__: Array[0]
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use controller as syntax you should not assign `Menus` object to `$scope` anymore. Instead you set corresponding `this` property (property of controller object, rather than `$scope` object):

```
app.controller('HeaderController', function($scope, $http) {
    var self = this;
    $http.get("/data/main_menu.php").success(function(data){
        self.Menus = data;
    });
});
```

<sub>I use `self` reference, because inside success callback `this` points to different context, not controller.</sub>

Read about different controller declaration styles [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController#example).

If you however want to go with `$scope.Menus = data;` way, `ngRepeat` should look like `<li ng-repeat="menu in Menus">{{ menu.name }}</li>`. With controller-as declaration you can still use `$scope` object of course.

Answer (score 1):

header.Menus is incorrect you must use Menus instead. Like this

```
<header ng-controller="HeaderController">
<ul id="menu_categories">
    <li ng-repeat="menu in Menus">{{ menu.name }}</li>
</ul>
```